# How do you get the Code Runner extension in Visual Studio Code to use the selected Python interpreter?

Tags: python, coderunner, vscode-code-runner

I'd like quickly run the active python file in vscode using the [Code Runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/) extension.

When I run it I get the message...

> Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640

I would like Code Runner to use the active vscdode Python Interpreter. How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>*This took some time to find so I thought I'd post the Q & A here for future searchers.*</sup>

From [this github post](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/272).
Open your `settings.json` file and add this setting.

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "python":"$pythonPath $fullFileName",
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I don't understand why everything is so complicated with VSCODE