# ModuleNotFoundError appears when running python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am given ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import libraries. I am on Mac Big Sur 11.6.1
[image]
[image]

Comment: Install numpy by running `pip install numpy`

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818811/import-error-no-module-named-numpy

Comment: it says "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.21.5)"

Comment: You are using Python 3.8.9, not 3.9

Comment: Your screenshot shows your VS Code is using a "Python 3.8.9" environment, and your comment about numpy "already satisfied" is from a "Python 3.9" environment. You have to make sure the Python where you installed numpy is the same Python you use to run jupyter.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of [How do you get Visual Studio Code to use different Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470563/how-do-you-get-visual-studio-code-to-use-different-python-interpreter) because the root issue is that you need to use the correct Python env.

Comment: I changed to Python 3.9.6 64-bit still shows the error..

Comment: Does it show "Python 3.9.6 64-bit" on the top right corner, same as your screenshot? Is that the same Python env where you installed numpy?

Comment: I added another pic showing that I have changed the environment but the issue is not solved

Comment: From the screenshot of your terminal, it seems you are using the Code Runner extension. You need to tell Code Runner to _also use the same Python interpreter_. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19797616/2745495, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57541747/2745495

Comment: an alternative way is to run `pip list` and it will tell if libraries are installed. If not either you install the libraries ; or through  `Python: Select Interpreter` ( `CTRL-SHIFT-P` ( `SHFT-OPTION-P` mac) and select the correct environment.

Answer (score 0):

After you switch to the `3.9.6` version of Python, it can find the `numpy` package.

So you need to install the rest of the packages: `matplotlib` and so on.

**Ctrl+Shif+P** -> **Python: Select Interpreter** -> **Ctrl+Shift+`** -> in the terminal execute **pip install matplotlib**